# Digital ocean kill the build process on docker

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Digital ocean kill docker process, why?

```
cache:
  untracked: true
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
  - .yarn
  - node_modules/
  - client/semantic/

before_script:
  - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
  - yarn install

stages:
  - build

Compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build:prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/
  cache:
    untracked: true
    key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
    paths:
    - dist/
```

After `2 minutes 34 seconds` ..

[image]

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Killed
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Why was killed?

I have a local environment, with same linux distribution+docker+gitlab runner. And locally works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the `Killed` message comes from the Linux OOM (Out Of Memory) killer. I'm betting if you check `dmesg` output you will find a OOM message about the process being killed because not enough memory was available. In this scenario, you'll need to give your system some more memory (or, in Digital Ocean case, there may not be any swap space and you could start by creating some).